# Implements time ago like youtube

Tags: android, timeago

How to distinguish 4weeks ago and 1month ago? I have the problem with it when I wrote testing code for it on android.

I think it depends on date when I tested. Do I think right? If my opinion is right then how can I make it well or passing the test codes?

One of my idea for passing test codes is holding now date for testing. Is there any ideas for me?

---

Sorry, I think my question is not clear. A part of my code is here.

```
assertEquals("a month ago", timeAgoWithAddedValue(Calendar.MONTH, -1));

private String timeAgoWithAddedValue(int field, int value) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(field, value);
    return timeAgo(cal.getTime());
}

public static final long WEEK_UNIT = DAY_UNIT * 7;
public static final long MONTH_UNIT = 2629746000L; // I found this value online, 1 Gregorian month -> ms
public static final long YEAR_UNIT = 31556952000L; // I found this value online, 1 Gregorian year -> ms

public String timeAgo(Date date) {
        long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        long sinceNowInMillis = now - date.getTime();

        ...
        if (sinceNowInMillis < MONTH_UNIT) {
            long weeks = sinceNowInMillis / WEEK_UNIT;
            // return proper ago string with weeks
        }

        if (sinceNowInMillis < YEAR_UNIT) {
            long months = sinceNowInMillis / MONTH_UNIT;
            // return proper ago string with months
        }
        ...
}
```

I wrote the code few month ago and it succeed at that time. But today the testing code failed. Because the code expected `4 weeks ago` instead. I wonder my code is wrong or the problem is depends on length of week so it's natural problems?

Comment: you can use an out of the box library such as this one https://github.com/kevinsawicki/java-timeago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get below function :

```
  public static String millisToLongDHMS(long duration) {
  if (duration > 0) {
     duration = new Date().getTime() - duration;
  }
  if (duration < 0) {
     duration = 0;
  }

  StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
  long temp = 0;
  if (duration >= ONE_SECOND) {
     temp = duration / ONE_DAY;
     if (temp > 0) {
        duration -= temp * ONE_DAY;
        res.append(temp).append(" day").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "")
                .append(duration >= ONE_MINUTE ? ", " : "");
     }

     temp = duration / ONE_HOUR;
     if (temp > 0) {
        duration -= temp * ONE_HOUR;
        res.append(temp).append(" hour").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "")
                .append(duration >= ONE_MINUTE ? ", " : "");
     }

     temp = duration / ONE_MINUTE;
     if (temp > 0) {
        duration -= temp * ONE_MINUTE;
        res.append(temp).append(" min").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "");
     }

     if (!res.toString().equals("") && duration >= ONE_SECOND) {
        res.append(" and ");
     }

     temp = duration / ONE_SECOND;
     if (temp > 0) {
        res.append(temp).append(" sec").append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "");
     }
     res.append(" ago");
     return res.toString();
  } else {
     return "Just Now";
  }
 }
```

**UPDATE**

you can use my another function:

```
  public static String getTimeAgo(long time) {
     if (time < 1000000000000L) {
     // if timestamp given in seconds, convert to millis
     time *= 1000;
  }

  long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
  if (time > now || time <= 0) {
     return null;
  }

  // TODO: localize
  final long diff = now - time;
  if (diff < MINUTE_MILLIS) {
     return "just now";
  } else if (diff < 2 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
     return "a minute ago";
  } else if (diff < 50 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
     return diff / MINUTE_MILLIS + " min ago";
  } else if (diff < 90 * MINUTE_MILLIS) {
     return "an hour ago";
  } else if (diff < 24 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
     return diff / HOUR_MILLIS + " hours ago";
  } else if (diff < 48 * HOUR_MILLIS) {
     return "yesterday";
  } else {
     return diff / DAY_MILLIS + " days ago";
  }
 }
```

Comment: Yes. but We dont need to add library for this simple logic. so, i created for my own. thank you

Comment: Yes. But, we don't need to add third party library for this simple logic. so i created for my own. thank you for the information

Answer (score 0):

you may use this line of code to achieve your goal without using any library in your project

```
 DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp, new Date().getTime(), DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS)
```

here `timestamp` is a long of time milliseconds

read more in documentation here [DateUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html)

**for example** if you pass timestamp as `1482739673913` you will get `6 minutes ago`

and if timestamp is  `1482582128877` you will get `2 days ago`

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out what is the problem. It depends on days of month.

The days of month are not the same(Oct:31, Nov:30, Dec:31..) but I'm using constant when I calculate it in my code.

I mean, if month has 31days then sinceNowInMillis in my code is less than MONTH_UNIT. So the result is '4 weeks ago' following my code. Because I calculated a target date using Calendar.add(Calender.MONTH, -1).

On the other hands, if month has 30days or less, sinceNowInMillis in my code is larger than MONTH_UNIT. so the result is '1 month ago' following my code.